# GNU make equivalent to BSD make's $(var:Q)?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, bsdmake

BSD make has a `:Q` variable expansion modifier, documented in [the FreeBSD make man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make%281%29) as follows:

```
:Q   Quotes every shell meta-character in the variable, so that it can be
     passed safely through recursive invocations of make.
```

If variable `var` has value `a b\c"d'e$f`, then `$(var:Q)` expands to `a\ b\\c\"d\'e\$f` (or something equivalent).  This is useful to pass strings to the shell without worrying that the shell will interpret any special characters.

Does GNU make have an equivalent?  Or do I have to escape special characters my own?

Comment: I can't see any such feature in the gnu make manual, but it's not surprising given the number of platforms and shells make must support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU make provides functions [`subst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) and `patsubst` which can help solve the problem.  Those are more *general*, but require more work by the developer since they do not solve the *specific* problem.  Also, the documentation does not show they use regular expressions, adding to the work.

For instance, you could in principle build up an expression like this:

```
$(subst \\,\\\\,$(subst ",\", $(subst ',\', var)))
```

For more discussion,

- *[Escaping comma and space in GNU Make](http://blog.jgc.org/2007/06/escaping-comma-and-space-in-gnu-make.html)*
- *[Can GNU make handle filenames with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838384/can-gnu-make-handle-filenames-with-spaces)*
- *[GNU Make, double quotes and lists](http://www.dctrwatson.com/2012/06/gnu-make-double-quotes-and-lists/)*

Comment: So I do have to roll my own.  Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

For *sh* variants, simply encase the expression in single quotes, changing any embedded single quote into `'"'"'`.

```
quote = '$(subst ','"'"',$1)'
```

Usage:

```
$(error [$(call quote,ab'c\ d$$f)])
```

Footnote: There is no way to quote anything inside single quotes. A second single quote thus closes the quoted expression. So, to handle an embedded single quote, close the single quotes with `'`, add a quoted single quote `"'"`, start another single-quoted string `'`.