# How to escape spaces inside a Makefile

Tags: makefile, escaping

Let's say I want to compile a C++ project located in `/home/me/Google Drive/Foobar/` into an executable named `Foobar`, and I want to use GNU Make in order to make that process automatic.

Here is what my Makefile looks like :

```
OUTPUT = $(notdir $(CURDIR))

all $(OUTPUT):
    g++ *.cpp -o $(OUTPUT)
```

The problem is, since there are spaces in the project's path, the `notdir` command is interpreting two separate paths and returns `Google Foobar`.

I've tried putting quotes around `$(CURDIR)` (`$(notdir "$(CURDIR)")`) but I get the following error :

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I don't understand where the problem comes from.

Also, I would appreciate an answer that does not involve changing the path name... Thanks :)

Comment: Does `$(notdir \"$(CURDIR)\")` work?

Comment: Nope, it returns `Google Foobar"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can GNU make handle filenames with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838384/can-gnu-make-handle-filenames-with-spaces)

Answer (score 6):

You can try replacing `space` with `_` in the `$(CURDIR)` and then fetch the `$(OUTPUT)`. Like below

```
null      :=
SPACE     := $(null) $(null)
OUTPUT     = $(notdir $(subst $(SPACE),_,$(CURDIR)))

all $(OUTPUT):
    g++ *.cpp -o $(OUTPUT)
```

So essentially after **`string substitution (subst)`**

```
$(OUTPUT) will be Foobar
```

Comment: As per the question's title, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is less on the GNU make side in storing the directory than it is on the shell expansion side. So change

```
 g++ *.cpp -o $(OUTPUT)
```

to:

```
 g++ *.cpp -o "$(OUTPUT)"
```

Using the variant of GNU make called [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) you might be able to see this more easily.

With *remake*, if you wanted to verify that the value of $OUTPUT has a space in it, you could run:

```
$ remake -X
GNU Make 4.1+dbg0.91
...
-> (/home/me/Google Drive/Makefile:3)
all: 
remake<0> expand OUTPUT
Makefile:1 (origin: makefile) OUTPUT := Google Drive
```

Now if you wanted to see a shell script that does the same actions that GNU make will run, use the *write* command:

```
remake<1> write all
File "/tmp/all.sh" written.
```

*all* above is the *make* target name. Then look at `/tmp/all.sh` which is just a shell script and you'll see you have the problem there, which of course can be fixed by adding the quotes.

Comment: this works..but it just fails inside commands like `(cd dir  && '$(MAKE)' )`

Answer (score 0):

It looks this combination works in this context.

```
OUTPUT = "$(notdir $(CURDIR))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
OUTPUT = $(notdir $(lastword $(CURDIR)))

all $(OUTPUT):
    g++ *.cpp -o $(OUTPUT)
```