# Escaping spaces in LIBS path Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, libmosquitto

I'm trying to include Eclipse Mosquitto library sample mosquitto example from [here](https://gist.github.com/evgeny-boger/8cefa502779f98efaf24)

I'm trying to use a Makefile to build and compile the code.

I'm facing an issue where the compiler/linker/whatsoever cannot find the mosquitto library located at C:\Program Files\Mosquitto\devel.
Here's the error:

```
mqtt-hostlink> make
gcc -Wall -o main main.c -LC:\\Program ,_,Files\\Mosquitto\\devel\mosquitto.lib
gcc: error: ,_,Files\Mosquitto\devel\mosquitto.lib: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:11: make] Error 1
```

Here's my Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
null      :=
SPACE     := $(null) $(null)

LIBS = -LC:\\Program$(SPACE),_,Files\\Mosquitto\\devel\mosquitto.lib

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< 

make: main.c
    $(CC) -Wall -o main $^ $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
```

The "space" method I referred from : [How to escape spaces inside a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687828/how-to-escape-spaces-inside-a-makefile#answer-30691137)

Comment: What about `LIBS = "C:\\Program Files\\Mosquitto\\devel\\mosquitto.lib"`? The option `-L` is for specifying *directories* that contain library files, not the library file itself. BTW: A Makefile rule  `make: main.c` should create a file `make` while your command creates `main`.

Comment: @Bodo Sorry I can't understand the last sentence. You mean a file called `make` is created using command `make: main.c`?

Comment: @hweiu321 -L should be used to specify the search directory for the libraries and -l be used to specify the library to bind, you can try like this LIBS = "C:\\Program Files\\Mosquitto\\devel -lmosquitto", not sure if make will append the .lib, you can also try "LIBS=-l C:\\Program Files\\Mosquitto\\devel\\mosquitto.lib"

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the short name for tar directory. List the directories with /X option as below

```
C:\>dir /X p*


 Directory of C:\

09/06/2021  02:24 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
09/06/2021  01:29 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
```

Then just use `PROGRA~1` instead of `Program Files`

Comment: It gives this error. I think `make` didn't understand the `~` shorthand.
`gcc -Wall -o main main.c "C:\Program~1\Mosquitto\devel\mosquitto.lib"
gcc.exe: error: C:\Program~1\Mosquitto\devel\mosquitto.lib: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:11: make] Error 1`

Answer (score 1):

There's some confusion here.  That post is about how to escape spaces from make functions.  You are not trying to invoke any make functions here, you are just trying to use a variable in a command line.  There's no need to escape anything from make.

What you need to do is escape the spaces from the shell, not from make.  You can do that easily, just using quotes.  No need for fancy make operations.  I recommend you also use forward-slashes, not backslashes.  Almost all Windows programs accept both forward and backslashes.  Only `cmd.exe` built-ins don't.

```
LIBS = "-LC:/Program Files/Mosquitto/devel/mosquitto.lib"
```

Comment: But when I run `make`, the compiler still cannot detect the #include <mosquitto.h> header file.

Comment: @hweiu321 To define a search directory for `#include` you need option `-I`. Assuming you updated your Makefile, please edit your question, **append** the new version and copy&paste both the compile command that gets executed and the full error message(s).

Comment: The error you showed us was a linker error.  There was no message about a missing header file in your question.