# Make in Cygwin with spaces in file names

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, avr-gcc

I feel like this may be a simple one, I have been stuck on it all day though. I am using Cygwin, and WinAVR to compile some files in the arduino library. I want to use a makefile, but I am having problems with spaces in file names (at least i think that is it). I made a link to bypass that, but that is not working either! There are a few SO questions already about spaces in file names but none of them helped me.

My makefile:

```
#ARDUINO_PATH=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino
ARDUINO_PATH=./link_to_arduino_dir
SRC=$(wildcard $(ARDUINO_PATH)/*.c)


all: echo $(SRC)

$(SRC):
    avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -I $(ARDUINO_PATH) -c -o . $@

echo:
    echo $(SRC)
```

After the wildcard, $SRC is empty. running this makefile will just have an empty "echo" then return.

**Edit:**

The link was created with

`ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino link_to_arduino_dir`

Simple commands like 'ls' work with it, which is why I am so confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can GNU make handle filenames with spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838384/can-gnu-make-handle-filenames-with-spaces)

Comment: The other question does not answer why the wildcard did not work with the symlink i created

Answer (score 2):

How about the old Windows trick of using DOS names (8.3)?

Instead of `/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/` use `/c/Progra~2/`.

**Note**: On a 64-bit Windows `Progra~1` will point to "Program Files" and `Progra~2` will point to "Program Files (x86)". If you're running on a 32-bit system, just use `Progra~1`.

Comment: Huh thats a neat trick! It works for me in cygwin ("ls /cygdrive/c/Progra~2/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/*.c" gets the correct list of files), but also does not work with wildcard :(