# How to pass a variable with spaces in its value as a single argument to a GNU make function?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is my Makefile.

```
MYPATH = /dir 1/file 1.txt

test1:
    echo $(notdir $(MYPATH))

test2:
    echo $(notdir "$(MYPATH)")

test3:
    echo TODO
```

My intention is to get just the `file 1.txt` portion of the path from
`/dir 1/file 1.txt`. Yes, this is a path with spaces in it.

I am unable to get the desired results.

```
$ make test1
echo dir file 1.txt
dir file 1.txt
```

In the above output, it appears that `notdir` was provided three separate
arguments: `/dir`, `1/file` and `1.txt` and as a result their `notdir`
parts were returned: `dir`, `file` and `1.txt`.

The following does not work at all.

```
$ make test2
echo dir file 1.txt"
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'test2' failed
make: *** [test2] Error 2
```

Why does it complain about "Unterminated quoted string"?

What is the right way to solve the problem. I want an output like the
following.

```
$ make test3
echo file 1.txt
file 1.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can GNU make handle filenames with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838384/can-gnu-make-handle-filenames-with-spaces)

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this question?