# How to write paths in Makefile for Windows

Tags: c++, gnu-make

I'm running Windows 10 and am trying to write a Makefile to compile a C++ file that uses the SFML library as well as the [nuklear](https://github.com/Immediate-Mode-UI/Nuklear) libraries. I have MinGW installed and added to my PATH, and I also have GNU Make installed and added to my PATH. So I can call both `make` and `gcc` from a Command Prompt window.

The Makefile I'm editing is:

```
# Install
CC = gcc
BIN = demo

# Flags
CFLAGS += -s -O2

SRC = main.cpp
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

# Edit the line below to point to your SFML folder on Windows
SFML_DIR = C:/SFML-2.5.1/

BIN := $(BIN).exe
LIBS = -lmingw32 -DSFML_STATIC -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32

SFML_INC = -I $(SFML_DIR)/include
SFML_LIB = -L $(SFML_DIR)/lib

$(BIN):
    $(CC) $(SRC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(SFML_INC) $(SFML_LIB) $(LIBS)
```

But as per the [nuklear documentation](https://github.com/Immediate-Mode-UI/Nuklear#building), I need to include `nuklear.h` in the Makefile. **For my project, I have a directory called `include` which contains `nuklear.h`.** The full path is similar to:

```
C:/Users/Me/Github Repositories/folder-1/folder-2/include/
```

So I make the following additions to the Makefile:

```
SFML_DIR = C:/SFML-2.5.1/
INCL_DIR = C:/Users/Me/Github Repositories/folder-1/folder-2/include/

$(BIN):
    # $(CC) $(SRC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(SFML_INC) $(SFML_LIB) $(LIBS)
    $(CC) $(SRC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) -I $(INCL_DIR) $(SFML_INC) $(SFML_LIB) $(LIBS)
```

I added the path to `nuklear.h` and have asked included it in compilation by specifying the `-I` flag. But I get the following error when I run `Make`:

```
makefile:23: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Now, there's a space in the path ("Github Reposities"). So I believe I need to add quotation marks to include the full path.

But when I add quotation marks to the full path, I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/Users/Me/Github', needed by `demo.exe'.  Stop.
```

So I'm missing something when it comes to specifying paths in a Makefile on Windows. How can I add a complete path in my Makefile when the path contains spaces?

Comment: I don’t see how your errors arise from that makefile, but does this answer your question? [Can GNU make handle filenames with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838384/can-gnu-make-handle-filenames-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

Firstly, I moved my project out of the `Github Repositories` directory and into a new directory with **no** spaces, `GitHub_Repositories`. That fixed the path issue.

Secondly, I had to insert a **tab**, not a **space**, before

```
$(CC) $(SRC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN) $(SFML_INC) $(SFML_LIB) $(LIBS)
```

Previously (as one can see in the original post), there were spaces there.

Comment: There is no issue with paths containing whitespace _in recipes_.  Make doesn't care about that: you just have to be sure you escape the spaces correctly for your shell.  What make doesn't like is whitespace in targets or prerequisites in the makefile.

Comment: But of course you must use a hard TAB to indent recipes.  You cannot use spaces.